# Select and copy range of cell after a specific string to another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, range, cell

I am working a VBA program and I want to copy a range of cell and then paste it new worksheet with the title being the string following the text "Delivery for"

> E.g. I want to copy range under "Delivery for Sam" and the name of the
>   new worksheet should be "Sam"

```
Dim N as long
N = Range(Cells(rcell, Col_Western).End(xlDown).Row)

With ActiveSheet
    For rcell = 1 To lastrow
        If InStr(1, Cells(rcell, Col_Western), "Delivery for", vbBinaryCompare) > 0 Then
            Range(ActiveCell & N).Select
            Selection.Copy After:=Worksheets(Sheets.Count)
            ActiveSheet.Name = "QBS"
        End If
    Next rcell
End With
```

Comment: I would imagine your first run-time error is on the second line.

Comment: @jeeped Yes, that seems to be problem but i cant seem to find the bug in it

Comment: Your code is a mess that contradicts itself, attempts to use unreferenced vars and doesn't use the vars it does allocate. Suggest you start over with the macro recorder.

Comment: I tried using the macro recorder, however the ranges that will be used will vary hence i cant reference a specific cell reference

Comment: Is N supposed to be the last row? If it is then I suggest calling it something like LastRow or LR or lRow.  LastRow= Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 
 where column 1 = column A.

Comment: Thank @Blake, however I want to select the range of cells until its blank and then copy the selected range to a new worksheet

Comment: You need to show an example of your worksheet your description is unclear. i.e. are your "Delivery for xxxx" strings in a row or column?

Comment: Also, if you are trying to add a worksheet and then paste the range from the current cell with "Delivery for xxxx" to the last use cell. Then you have to do a `Worksheets.Add` and then copy the range to the new worksheet. You can't do a `Selection.Copy` to no worksheet.

Comment: @GMalc its a row, so basically, if the program scrolls the cell and finds a cell with "Delivery for xxxx" then it will select the cells until it finds the empty cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested, written on mobile. Might work, might not, but might give you some idea on how to go about achieving it.

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

Dim sourceSheet as worksheet
'Change this to the name of the sheet which contains the data you want to separate by name. I assume Sheet1'
Set sourceSheet = Thisworkbook.worksheets("Sheet1")

With sourceSheet

Dim westernColumn as long
' If this can change (based on the location of the data), you need to work out some logic to assign it dynamically. If this does not change, turn it into a constant and assign to whatever column number it should be. I arbitrarily pick column 5 (column E) as an example '
westernColumn = 5

Dim lastRow as long
lastRow = .cells(.rows.count, westernColumn).end(xlup).row

End with

Dim rowIndex as long
Dim deliveryName as string
Dim characterIndex as long

For rowIndex = 1 to lastRow

characterIndex = InStr(1, sourcesheet.Cells(rowIndex, westernColumn).value2, "Delivery for ", vbBinaryCompare)

If characterIndex > 0 Then

deliveryName = VBA.strings.mid$(sourcesheet.Cells(rowIndex, westernColumn).value2, characterindex + 13) '+13 is a magic number used to exclude "Delivery for " string itself, implement it in a better way if possible'

With thisworkbook.worksheets.add
' this line below might cause an error if a sheet with this name already exists or if deliveryName is illegal in some way. Maybe code some defensive checks before assigning sheet name.
.name = deliveryName

' This includes the "Delivery for " row when copy-pasting  and assumes each there is a blank row before each "Delivery for " row. '
sourceSheet.range(sourcesheet.Cells(rowIndex, westernColumn), sourcesheet.Cells(rowIndex, westernColumn).end(xldown)).copy .range("A1")

End with

End if

' you should probably have two variables: startRow and endRow, where startRow = first "Delivery for ", and endRow = next "Delivery for "

' but I don't have time to do this at the moment.'

Next rowIndex ' should increment rowIndex by number of rows pasted - 1, so that pasted rows are not needlessly checked for "Delivery for " string '

End sub
```